# What is the minimal possible length of an $n$-universal word?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, optimization, extremal-combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Suppose $A$ is a finite alphabet. Let's call a word $w \in A^*$ $n$ -universal iff it contains every word from $A^n$ as a subword. What is the minimal possible length of an $n$-universal word over $A$? $|A| = m$.

It is definitely $\geq m^n + n - 1$ , because a word of length $m \geq n$ has $m - n + 1$ subwords of length $n$.

I think, that $|A|^n + n - 1$ is quite likely to be the exact answer, but do not know how to prove it.

It holds, however, for the following particular cases:

$m = 1$: $a^n$

$n = 2, m = 2$: $abbaa$

$n = 3, m = 2$: $abbbaaabab$

$n = 2, m = 3$: $ccacaabbcba$